# How to create Adaptive card and continue dialog on specific response in azure bot node v4

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I am currently trying to create a waterfall that starts with an adaptive card.

Originally I had the waterfall working with ChoicePrompt on every step, but on step 1 I wanted 2 choices to openUrl - so changed to an adaptive card to start (is this required or is there a way to openUrl from a specific response in ChoicePrompt the user gives?)

The issue here is that every response (that isn't the openUrl buttons) leads to the adaptive card to repeat itself rather than pass the non-openUrl choice to the next step of the dialog.

I am also storing each dialog response (currently in an array, which I clear at the end of the dialog) to perform a certain action based on all responses combined (is there a better way to save user responses than pushing into an array?)

```
var answers = [];
async firstStep(stepContext) {
    var send = {
        text: 'question',
        attachments: [
            {
              "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
              "content": {
                "text": null,
                "buttons": [
                  {
                    "type": "imBack",
                    "title": "one",
                    "value": "one"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "openUrl",
                    "title": "two",
                    "value": "https://example.com"
                  },
                  {
                    "type": "openUrl",
                    "title": "three",
                    "value": "https://example.com"
                  },                                            
                ]
              }
        }
        ]
    }
    return await stepContext.context.sendActivity(send);
}
async secondStep(stepContext) {
    const resp = stepContext.result.value;
    answers.push(resp);
            
    return await stepContext.prompt('ChoicePrompt', {
        prompt: questions[1],
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(options[1]),
        style: ListStyle.suggestedAction
    });
}
async thirdStep(stepContext) {
    const resp = stepContext.result.value;
    answers.push(resp);
    return await stepContext.prompt('ChoicePrompt', {
        prompt: questions[2],
        choices: ChoiceFactory.toChoices(options[2]),
        style: ListStyle.suggestedAction
    });
}
async finalStep(stepContext) {
    const resp = stepContext.result.value;
    answers.push(resp);
    
    // get func
    var fun = await this.func(answers);
    //do stuff with what function returns
    
    // reset quiz
    answers = [];
    return await stepContext.endDialog();    
}
```

So to summarise, the initial adaptive card, I would like it to continue to repeat itself if anything other than `one` is returned, but if `one` is returned I would like it to move onto the next part of the dialog with that value, and save that value (maybe better than I do above).

Lastly, if there is an easy way to openUrl in the current tab and not a new one that would be great.

Any insight here on how to work with hero cards would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the step dictionary to store your values?

Comment: I am using the array `answers` as above. How would I use the step dictionary?

Comment: Adaptive Cards and hero cards are two different things. Which one are you trying to use? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @KyleDelaney hero card it'd seem `application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero`

Comment: @JDT - I'm pretty confused about what you're trying to do here. If your hero card contains only one button that sends a message to the bot, why have that button at all? Why not just display a card with two openUrl buttons and then immediately proceed to the next step without waiting for user input? Also, it sounds like you're saying you cannot proceed to the next step of the waterfall, and this may be because you're not saving the changes to your bot state. Can you take your hero card out of the equation and see if you can manage to get a normal waterfall to work with simple text?

Comment: @JDT - Are you still working on this?